# hiding and displaying responsive code with @media query

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I'm trying to create a responsive code to get the best of both worlds from iframes and HTML 5 video with clickable links. In my set up I want to write an inline @media query to play only the Iframe when bigger than 375px and if smaller than 375px to play HTML video in the same div block `item white`

I'm getting stuck on how to display hidden and instead show `<video>`

and my boss is convinced this is the way he wants to do it :S

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) {
  div.video {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  }
}

div.video>iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item white">
  <div class="video">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TIB3q68ZHYw" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="item white">
  <a href="https://www.walmart.com">
    <video width="100%" height="100%" loop autoplay muted preload="metadata"> . 
    <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/274117996.sd.mp4? 
    s=d8982e09554557a0a5db18f8c5d450252fbcddbc&profile_id=165" 
    type="video/mp4" />      
      
    Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade 
    your browser.
    </video>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In css, (min-width:500px) means that anything above 500px will trigger the css below that. If you instead say (max-width:500px), that means anything below 499px will trigger the css under that. For example:

```
/* This will effect the class as long as the screen width is > 500px */
@media (min-width:500px) {
  .myContent {
    display:none;
  }
}

/* This will effect the class as long as the screen width is < 500px */
@media (max-width:500px) {
  .myContent {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Does this help a little bit?

Comment: yes it does, I think i need to combine my two div together so that will be treated as a single asset with two content condition at > or < that 375px. i will keep testing

Comment: Something like comparing between 375px to 500px?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is (as you've noted) to combine the elements under one containing `div` and hide/show the content respectively (although the containing div here is moot). So with each breakpoint being reached, the iframe will be hidden and the video shown (and vice versa).

I couldn't get your mp4 file to play, so I've substituted it with an example as this may have impacted your effort and those of other responders...

Simple CSS:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 375px) {
   #iframe {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
   #video {
    display: none;
   }
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
   #video {
     display: block;  
   }

   #iframe {
     display: none;
   }
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="item white">    
   <div id="iframe">
     <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TIB3q68ZHYw" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="video">
     <video width="100%" height="100%" loop autoplay muted preload="metadata">
     <source src="https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4" 
type="video/mp4" />      

  Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade 
your browser.
     </video>
   </div>
 </div>
```

You can find this code working in a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zh2b0n1e/

You will need to adjust the CSS styling elements to suit your needs (padding, width, borders etc) and improve the HTML, but this method is a simple way of achieving your goal.

Comment: Thanks, the only issue I am running into with your code is that the iframe is no longer responsive without the  `div.videov { position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 }
}
div.videov > iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}`